# Sh'kiya alarm app (iOS)

Tags: product-recommendation, technology, zemanim, phone

Since the time-change, I have been rather off in calculating when I should say minchah. Is there an app which has an alarm for sh'kiya (or secular sundown timing if they differ) which is available for iOS?

Comment: I see several apps to tell you when it is, but none seem to let you set an alert.

Answer (score 9):

[Ultimate Zmanim](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/ultimate-zmanim-premiere-app/id452921604?mt=8) for iOS has that feature.

> With Zmanim Alarms, Ultimate Zmanim can remind you of important zmanim throughout the day. Shema, Tefila, and weekly candle lighting are all covered.

(To forewarn the question, on Android, [Halachic Times](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sf.times) is an equivalent).

Comment: I'm the developer of Ultimate Zmanim. Thanks for the plug!